# Converting an IF condition to a mathematical equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, computer-science

I am trying to study about converting algorithms into mathematical equations. For this I just started with a simple random example :

```
function set_b( int b):int
{
    if ( b >= 0)
    {
     a = 5 ; 
    }
    else
    if ( b < 0 )
    {
     a = -20  
    } 


}
```

By looking at the above algorithm, one can say :

a is dependent upon b. So :  a = f(b). Also, the two blocks of Ifs are actually talking about -ve and +ve number lines.

But after this i get stuck, where to start approaching the solution from. Some equation like

a = b + blah blah - blah blah * blah blah  etc.

Any clues or hints pls ?

Comment: And what if $b=0$?

Comment: ok, b < 0  is now b <= 0 . Actually it's not important what equality it has. What i wanna focus on is how to solve such if conditions mathematically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try
$$ a = \frac{5}{2}\left( 5 \frac{b}{|b|} - 3 \right) $$
If you just want to shorten your code, I suggest using the ternary operator like (`C++` style)

```
int set_b(int b) {
    int a = (b<0)?-20:5;
    return a;
};
```

Comment: How did you get the equation ?, a = 5/2 ( 5 b/|b| -3 ) ?  Any logical approach ?

Comment: Find $\alpha,\beta$ such that $a = \alpha \frac{b}{|b|}+\beta$. You have two conditions thus two equations with two variables.

Comment: But what if `b=0`? Then the `b/abs(b)` logic for getting the sign fails. Is there a way to adjust the equation to account for 0?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: try using the function $b / |b|$ (which is $1$ for $b > 0$, -1 for $b< 0$), as a building block, and then applying a couple elementary transforms (vertical dilation and translation) to get what you want.

Answer (score 4):

One way could be:

$$a = f(b) = \begin{cases} 5& b < 0\\-20& b > 0\end{cases}$$

Do you see something that could help this? What about the $b = 0$ case.

Can you see how to also define it using the Heaviside Unit Step function as an alternate solution?

Sorry that I have not yet learned the TeX style to make this look proper.

Answer (score 1):

let $a=f(b)$  ;then code says that for all $b>=0$  ,$a=5$ and for all input $b<0$,$a=-20$,this is  if we consider into mathematical term,likely piecewise  function